# How to optimize LINQ-2-SQL expression?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a fairly complicated query that would read from a table, then do group on CONTACT_ID, then select only those group with count of 1.

This query is fairly complicated and I have no idea how to optimize it in LINQ.

```
    var linkTable = this.DB.Links
        .Where(l=>l.INSTANCE_ID==123456 && l.CONTACT_ID.HasValue && l.ORGANISATION_ID.HasValue)
        .Select(l => new { l.DEFAULT_LINKED_ORGANISATION, l.LINK_ID, l.CONTACT_ID });

    var defaultOrganizationLinkQuery = linkTable
        .Where(l => l.DEFAULT_LINKED_ORGANISATION)
        .Select(l => l.LINK_ID);

    var singleOrganizationLinkQuery = linkTable
        .GroupBy(l => l.CONTACT_ID)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            CONTACT_ID = group.Key,
            contact_link_count = group.Count(),
            LINK_ID = group.First().LINK_ID
        })
        .Where(l => l.contact_link_count == 1)
        .Select(l => l.LINK_ID);

    var merged = singleOrganizationLinkQuery.Union(defaultOrganizationLinkQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made shorter version, but I do not expect it to be faster. If it works and is not slower I would be satisfied:

```
 var merged = this.DB.Links
        .Where(l=>l.INSTANCE_ID==123456 && l.CONTACT_ID.HasValue && l.ORGANISATION_ID.HasValue)
        .GroupBy(l => l.CONTACT_ID)
        .SelectMany(s => s.Where(x => s.Count() == 1 || x.DEFAULT_LINKED_ORGANISATION)
                          .Select(link => link.LINK_ID));
```